# How make a View that fit the parent or wrap the content in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I just started to develop IOS app and i come from Android.

In IOS I'm having problem to set the width and height of the View in my Layout.

**How can i set in IOS the weight and hight of a View like in Android when I set "Wrap Content" or "Match Parent"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS apps development there is a feature of "Auto Layout" which is used for setting the dynamic behavior of controls based on device size, resolution and orientation changes.

You can set the `anchor` settings for your view or setup constraints in reference to other UI elements to setup the behavior of controls for resizing the controls at run time. Xcode's inbuilt IB tool provides rich interface for testing the UI on all different iOS devices and orientations.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html